# Is there a reference for the syntax of the persistent quasiquoter?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I've read through [the chapter on persistent in the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent/). It gives lots of examples but leaves some things unexplained.

For example what does `Gt Desc` in this entity definition mean?

```
-- Define our entities as usual
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    firstName String
    lastName String
    age Int Gt Desc
    deriving Show
|]
```

Is there somewhere a definitive reference of all those extra attributes?

Comment: You can get some information by using the [package index on hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-1.3.0.6/docs/doc-index.html). So `Gt` is a filter option and `Desc` is for query ordering. Not sure why they are used in the schema definition itself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a Wiki page covering the syntax](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Persistent-entity-syntax). The `Gt` and `Desc` is an old syntax that's no longer needed, I'll remove the references from the chapter (I thought I'd caught them all already).

Comment: TIL there is a yesod wiki. This will drastically reduce the amount of future questions on SO :-)

Comment: The reference is now located in the hackage documentation for persistent : https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.13.2.1/docs/Database-Persist-Quasi.html